# How can I insert a space between two $_POST functions

Tags: php, textbox, space

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Write to a text file</title>
</head>
<body>
Add your text
<form action="" method='post'>
<input name='textblock'></input>
<input name='otherblock'></input>
<input type='submit' value='Add text'>

</form>

<?php

// Open the text file
$f = fopen("texties.txt", "a");

// Write text
fwrite($f, $_POST["textblock"] . $_POST["otherblock"] . "\r\n");

// Close the text file
fclose($f);

$filecontents = file_get_contents("texties.txt");
print nl2br($filecontents);
?>

</body> 
</html>
```

Which produces whatever the user enters in the text box, for instance "blue" and "buffalo" as

bluebuffalo

How can I get it to read

blue buffalo

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know what `. "\r\n"` does? Just put something alike with a space instead between your two variables.

Answer (score 2):

This can do the trick:

```
fwrite($f, $_POST["textblock"]." ". $_POST["otherblock"] . "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

you will kick yourself when you see this  but its simple:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Write to a text file</title>
</head>
<body>
Add your text
<form action="" method='post'>
<input name='textblock'></input>
<input name='otherblock'></input>
<input type='submit' value='Add text'>

</form>

<?php

// Open the text file
$f = fopen("texties.txt", "a");

// Write text
fwrite($f, $_POST["textblock"] . " " . $_POST["otherblock"] . "\r\n");

// Close the text file
fclose($f);

$filecontents = file_get_contents("texties.txt");
print nl2br($filecontents);
?>

</body> 
</html>
```